# How to evolve object in java / android keeping compatibility

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've developed a project which has two apps. One for final consumer and the other for the store/merchand, both sharing the same database in Firebase.
In user app I had to add an information in user registration data. At the merchand app, I have to make the same update to properly fetch user data.
I'm not sure what is the best practice to evolve the 'user data' class.

My main doubt relies on the fact that if I try to fetch data using the "old version" of the class in merchand's app code, but the information in data base has a new property it will brake.
One way I see is to update both apps with new property and assure that the merchand has the last version, which embodies the new property, before release the update version to customers. Proceeding this way I assure that merchand app will be able to fetch user data with or without the new property (objects stored without the new property will receive null value after fetching).
It doesn't seem to be a practical solution and I'm wondering what is the best practices for this kind of situation.

Should I create a new class (like, user_data_v2) which has the new property and in the merchand app, write a code to identify what class the download object belongs to? Should I have written merchand's app code this way for all objects that may be update in future? Or, the best way is to update the class and not create a new class?

I hope I have made myself clear and did not complicate a silly question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're thinking of this in the wrong way.  You aren't uploading classes.  You're uploading data.  Your implementation may parse that into a class, but you shouldn't think of it in that way-  it's too rigid and you'll miss obvious solutions.  Instead think of it as data, that can come in multiple versions.  Your app needs to be able to take that data, figure out the version, and parse it based on the rules for that version.  Don't think of your data as being the sameas  your class structure.  Your db schema and your class hierarchy don't need to be, and frequently shouldn't be, one to one.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Gabe. You are right, I'm using Firebase sdk I parse data into a class, and I've done it throuout the whole project. I simply retrieve the data at a specific knot, receiving it as 'dataSnapshot' object, then I parse that into the class. This is why it breaks if loaded data has a property that my class doesn't. 
I'll find a solution to identify if a specific property exists on that data and parse it accordingly.

@StephenC, I apologize. Question edited.